# Get the label of a MathJax equation

Tags: mathjax

How can I get the label of an equation? I'm attempting to reprocess an equation with a label, but I have to delete the label from `MathJax.Extension["TeX/AMSmath"].labels` first, for which the label must be known...

I know I can scan through the source text for the label `MathJax.Hub.getAllJax("mathDiv")[0}.SourceElement().find("\label(")` (...), but this seems needlessly complicated. Is there a better way?

Comment: Are you primarily asking if there's a built-in API for this or are you looking for more robust ways for finding the relevant IDs?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger built-in would be preferrable, but if that's not an option, a robust way would be acceptable. My current solution is to simply refresh the label-list using `MathJax.Extension["TeX/AMSmath"].labels = {}`, which seemed to have solved my problem in my case, but I could imagine the solution could be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in API for this.

If you don't need to keep labels, then the reset [in the comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45637710/get-the-label-of-a-mathjax-equation#comment78302972_45637710) is probably the best way to go about it:

```
MathJax.Extension["TeX/AMSmath"].labels = {}
```

A quick and dirty way to get the IDs is to leverage the fact that they end up in the output. So you can just get all the IDs in the output, e.g.,

```
const math = MathJax.Hub.getAllJax()[0];
const nodesWithIds = document.getElementById(math.root.inputID).previousSibling.querySelectorAll('[id]');
const ids = [];
for (node of nodesWithIds) ids.push(node.id);
```

A cleaner and perhaps conceptually easier way would be to leverage MathML (which is essentially the internal format): the `\label{}` always ends up on an `mlabeledtr`. The trouble is that you'd have to re-parse that, e.g.,

```
const temp = document.createElement('span');
temp.innerHTML = math.root.toMathML();
const nodesWithIds = temp.querySelectorAll('mlabeledtr [id]');
const ids = [];
for (node of nodesWithIds) ids.push(node.id);
```

This will make sure the array only has relevant IDs in them (and the contents of the nodes should correspond to `\label{}`.

I suppose with helper libraries it might be easier to dive into the `math.root` object directly and look for IDs recursively (in its `data` key).